# How to fix the error: No executable found matching command "dotnet-install"

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I installed the `dotnetcore 2.1.0-preview1-final` and running the following command to install the certs.

`dotnet install tool dotnet-dev-certs -g --version 2.1.0-preview1-final`

But I get the error:

`No executable found matching command "dotnet-install"`

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet tool install ...` instead? At some point `dotnet install tool` was changed to `dotnet tool install`.

Comment: I can choose your reply as answer if you can move your above comment as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Before the release of 2.1.0 SDK - the one that introduce the `tool` feature - the `dotnet install tool` command was changed to `dotnet tool install`.

In fact, the current guideline is that all commands should be of the form:

```
$ dotnet [context] [action]
```

So, for example:

```
$ dotnet tool install
$ dotnet new console
$ dotnet sln add ...
$ dotnet sln remove ...
```

The only context that is implicit is "project", because of historical reasons. In the future, the following might work:

```
$ dotnet project restore
$ dotnet project build
```

See the [official guidelines](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/cli-syntax-guideline.md) for more information on the current designs of commands.